# Vertical menu item state change - position over right border - what to do with scrollbar?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and am trying to do something a little "out of the box" with the accordion menu. In short, I want to create a hover and selected state that visually connects the selected parent menu item visually to the right content pane. Basically, it's kind of like a vertical tab system.

The only way I could get this to work is using position: fixed, which takes the item out of the flow of the rest of the menu. That's not really what I want. I want it to stay in the flow.

Here's a screenshot of what I have so far:

[image: [vertical menu example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRPCM.jpg)]

I like the fact that the hover state (which I'll need to preserve with JS once I get this working right) jumps over top of the scrollbar. The scrolling also still works when not hovering that item. I'd be open to feedback on the UI experience of this idea if anyone has any.

Here is the code I'm using to do this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container100 h-100 mainbg">
        <div class="menu-container row nomargin">
            <div class="nopadding leftmenu | border-0 border-end border-secondary 
                     vh-100 position-sticky top-0 ps-0 pe-0 overflow-x-hidden">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button id="home" class="bg-transparent noborder active-button mt-2 invert">
                        <img id="logo" src="images/overholt-logo.png" width="200">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion .accordion-flush bg-transparent" id="accordionExample">
                    <div class="accordion-item">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="dashboard">
                            <button id="Dash" class="accordion-button"
                                type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsedashboard"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsedashboard">
                                Dashboard
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="collapsedashboard" class="accordion-collapse collapse ps-4 bg-transparent text-light"
                            aria-labelledby="headingdashboard" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                            <div class="accordion-body pt-1 pb-1">
                                <button id="DashSales" class="bg-transparent noborder text-secondary nopadding active-button">
                                    Sales Person</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-body pt-1 pb-1 text-secondary">
                                <button id="DashPurch" class="bg-transparent noborder text-secondary nopadding active-button">
                                    Purchaser</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-body pt-1 pb-1 text-secondary">
                                <button id="DashAdmin" class="bg-transparent noborder text-secondary nopadding active-button">
                                    Admin Asst</button>
                            </div>

                            <div class=".accordion-flush noborder bg-transparent" id="subaccordionExample">
                                <div class="accordion-item border-0 bg-transparent">
                                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="dealerportal">
                                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed pt-2 pb-2 bg-transparent text-secondary" type="button"
                                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsedealerportal" aria-expanded="false"
                                            aria-controls="collapsedealerportal">
                                            Dealer Portal
                                        </button>
                                    </h2>
                                    <div id="collapsedealerportal" class="accordion-collapse collapse ps-3 bg-transparent text-secondary"
                                        aria-labelledby="headingdealerportal" data-bs-parent="#subaccordionExample">
                                        <div class="accordion-body pt-1 pb-1">
                                            <button id="DashSales" class="bg-transparent noborder text-secondary nopadding active-button">
                                                Orders</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="accordion-body pt-1 pb-1">
                                            <button id="DashSales" class="bg-transparent noborder text-secondary nopadding active-button">
                                                Inventory</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="accordion-body pt-1 pb-1">
                                            <button id="DashSales" class="bg-transparent noborder text-secondary nopadding active-button">
                                                Maintenance</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="accordion-body pt-1 pb-1">
                                            <button id="DashSales" class="bg-transparent noborder text-secondary nopadding active-button">
                                                Commissions</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

.accordion-item repeats for all the parent elements, so I didn't include the whole block of code.

**SCSS**

```
.menu-container {
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 10px 0px 40px var(--blktrans27)!important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(70deg, var(--dkgrayblue1), var(--dkgrayblue2));
}

.leftmenu {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
}

.accordion{
    /* border: 1px solid #ffffff21;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.213); */
    margin: 10px 0px;
    background-color:rgba(240, 255, 255, 0.201);
    width: 300px;
}
.accordion-item {
    @extend .border-0;
    @extend .bg-transparent;
}
.accordion-button {
    @extend .collapsed;
    @extend .pt-2;
    @extend .pb-2;
    @extend .bg-transparent;
    @extend .lightestblue;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    /* background-color: #212529!important; */
    height: 35px;
    border: 0px solid #ffffff5e;
    font-size: 17px;
    // color: var(--ltblueslate)!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
        &:hover {
            background-color: rgb(53 56 64)!important;
            border-top: 1px solid #ffffff5e;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff5e;
            border-left: 0px solid #ffffff5e;
            border-right: 1px solid rgb(53 56 64);
            border-radius: 0px!important;
            position: fixed;
            width:300px;
            z-index:1000;
        }
        &:focus {
            background-color: #292c33!important;
            border: 0px solid #ffffff5e;
            box-shadow: none;
            border-top: 1px solid #ffffff5e;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff5e;
            border-left: 0px solid #ffffff5e;
            border-radius: 0px!important;
        }
        &:active {
            background-color: #292c33!important;
            border: 0px solid #ffffff5e;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.0rem rgba(13,110,253,.25);
            border-top: 1px solid #ffffff5e;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff5e;
            border-left: 0px solid #ffffff5e;
            border-radius: 0px!important;
        }
        &::before {
            scale: 140%;
            position: relative;
            top: 3px;
            left: -8px
        }
        &::after {
            background-image: --bgcaret;
            filter:brightness(20);
        }
}
```